# Cast HttpPostedFileBase to Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, casting, stream, httppostedfilebase

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project in in C#, trying to get upload a document from a form to my database. 
I'm currently in my controller where I have imported the file as HttpPostedFileBase, and it has to be converted to type Stream. 
How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

```
HttpPostedFileBase document = form.DocumentFile;

Stream documentConverted = ?;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
var document = form.DocumentFile;
Stream documentConverted = document.InputStream;
```

Got it! I have to use `.Inputstream` to convert it directly.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis . it saved my time a lot.